# How to process Dataframe data in parallel way to call url with bulk of params

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to read .csv file which has Players info. I have to get the country from this csv and append it to url for further process.

At first I load the .csv data into data-frame. then I do loop on it to append the nationality to url as code below:

```
    val inputDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).load(getClass.getResource("/FifaData.csv").getPath).toDF()
    var url = ""
    val baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/countries/search?"

    val nationalityDF = inputDF.select("Nationality").distinct.rdd.zipWithIndex()
    nationalityDF.foreach { case (nationality, idx) =>
        val url = s"${baseUrl}page=${idx}&nameList=${nationality.get(0)}"
        println("url:: " + url)
    }
```

I wonder if I can avoid for-each to process the data and call the link with out for-each?

Comment: **Spark** is already _distributed_, this should execute in _parallel_ as long as the DF is big enough and you have available executors. If testing in local, ensure you give at least two CPUs to **Spark** `master("local[2]")` _(you can change 2 for any number you want, or use `*` to tell spark to use them all)_. Also, do not mutate `url` and `page`, page will fail as this is distributed, use a `zipWithIndex` instead. And for `url` just do `val url = baseUrl + "page=" + pageIndex + "&nameList=" + nationality.getString(0)` inside the `foreach`, that way every execution will have its own variable.

Comment: Thanks much for your reply. I'm not sure that I got the idea how to use a zipWithIndex with data-frame loop.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You can do this: `val nationalityDF = inputDF.select("Nationality").as[String].distinct.rdd.zipWithIndex()` and then this: `nationalityDF.foreach { case (nationality, idx) => val url = s"${baseUrl}page=${idx}&nameList=${nationality}" }`.

Comment: Thank you, thats work fine. But how can I avoid the for-each? Is there any way to process the data and call the link with out for-each? I edited the question above to use the correct code you share and to explain what I need to enhance.

Comment: Why you do not want to use `foreach`, what is your ultimate goal? What do you want a _"bulk"_ of names? Do you need to _execute_ the URL or only built it? The question is not clear. - Anyways, I, a professor myself, believe you are a bit confused about what is **Spark** and how it works, I would recommended you reading more before trying to code. But that, is just my humble opinion.

Comment: Yes I'm still beginner with  spark. The task I'm trying to solve wants to call the url and parse its json result to get info. 
The url takes list of string as nameList and pageIndex like: http://localhost:8080/countries/search?page=0&nameList=eeee,rrrr,tttt,uuuu where the nameList=eeee,rrrr,tttt,uuuu are taken from the csv file.

Comment: How many names do you want for each call? How does the page index affect the result? How is the output of the request? How do you expect to process such output? The question is very vague, try organizing everything, creating a **MCVE** and opening a new more concise question. Remember to do not ask for too many things at once, maybe start by just asking how to create the appropriate URL.

Comment: Absolutely true. I'm trying to organize things here and be more specific. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation is already parallelised, so cheers!

To add more details:
`foreach` in spark is an `action` which is used to perform some operations with side effects. It operates on RDD in executor JVM if spark is running in cluster mode.

If you want to get rid of `foreach` all together then you can translate it into an UDF and call it. However, this is not a good practice because, based on your example, you are not looking to get any result back from REST API. *Caution: Ugliness Ahead*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val inputDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).load(getClass.getResource("/FifaData.csv").getPath).toDF()
var url = ""
val baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/countries/search?"

val nationalityDF = inputDF.select("Nationality").distinct.rdd.zipWithIndex()
                           .asDF("nationality", "index")

val callRestApi: (nationality, idx)=> String = {
    val url = s"""${baseUrl}page=${idx}&nameList=${nationality.mkString(",")}"""
    println("url:: " + url)
    null
}

nationalityDF.withColumn("placeHolder", callRestApi($"nationality", $"index")).drop("placeHolder")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But still I pass nameList=${nationality.get(0)} as single value. I'm wondering how can I send bulk of names as list when call the api?
http://localhost:8080/countries/search?page=0&nameList=eeee,rrrr,tttt,uuuu

Comment: Question didn't specify anything of that sort, anyhow, its a Scala exercise, I have updated the answer.